# Read checbox only when true from DataGrid

Tags: c#

I have the following code that validates the true boxes, if they are true it executes the method and creates the triggers for the marked table

```
  public void crear_trigger1()
        {
          try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow r_tabla in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(r_tabla.Cells[0].Value);
                    if (isChecked)
                    {
                    string creacion_tri_in = "";
                    string creacion_tri_Up = "";
                    string creacion_tri_eli = "";
                    string columnas_orig = "";
                    campos_tablas = new DataTable();
                    campos_tablas = Traer_informacion("SELECT  COL.name AS columna,TYP.name AS Tipo, Longitud = CASE TYP.name  WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN COL.LENGTH/2 WHEN 'varchar' THEN COL.LENGTH/2 ELSE COL.LENGTH END  FROM dbo.syscolumns COL JOIN dbo.sysobjects OBJ ON OBJ.id = COL.id JOIN dbo.systypes TYP ON TYP.xusertype = COL.xtype  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysforeignkeys FK ON FK.fkey = COL.colid AND FK.fkeyid=OBJ.id  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects OBJ2 ON OBJ2.id = FK.rkeyid  LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns COL2 ON COL2.colid = FK.rkey AND COL2.id = OBJ2.id   WHERE OBJ.name =  '" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "' AND (OBJ.xtype='U' OR OBJ.xtype='V') and COL.colstat!=1 group by  COL.name ,TYP.name, COL.LENGTH ", set_getcadena_orginen);
                    creacion_tri_in = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_insertarLog_" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] AFTER  insert AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid group by client_net_address)   SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;";
                    creacion_tri_Up = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_ActualizarLog_" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] AFTER  update AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid  group by client_net_address)  SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF; ";
                    creacion_tri_eli = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_EliminarLog_" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] AFTER  delete AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid  group by client_net_address)  SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;";
                    for (int j = 0; j < campos_tablas.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == campos_tablas.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            columnas_orig += "" + campos_tablas.Rows[j]["columna"].ToString() + " ";
                        }
                        else
                               if (j < campos_tablas.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            columnas_orig += "" + campos_tablas.Rows[j]["columna"].ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    //TRIGGER INSERT
                    creacion_tri_in += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + " ,[TRANSACCION1],   [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1] ,C_ejecutada,Puesto_T) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'INSERCION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50) ,HOST_NAME()  as esta FROM INSERTED ) SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; ";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_in, set_getcadena_orginen);
                    //TRIGGER UPDATE 
                    creacion_tri_Up += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + " ,[TRANSACCION1] ,  [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1],C_ejecutada ,Puesto_T) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'ACTUALLIZACION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50 ),HOST_NAME()  as esta  FROM INSERTED )SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_Up, set_getcadena_orginen);
                    //TRIGGER DELETE
                    creacion_tri_eli += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + ",[TRANSACCION1] ,  [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1],C_ejecutada,Puesto_T ) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'ELIMINACION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50  ) ,HOST_NAME()  as esta  FROM DELETED)SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; ";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_eli, set_getcadena_orginen);
                }
                    MessageBox.Show("You must select the rows");
                    return;
            }
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                set_geterror = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Two are marked, those two create the trigger

[image]

But when they are not continuous, create the first one only and the others that are marked do not create them

What I need is that no matter if they are in order or not, I execute the triggers

that is, go through only those that are true

This is the code that understands if it is true or not

```
try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow r_tabla in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(r_tabla.Cells[0].Value);
                    if (isChecked)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistent code formatting and indentation **is important**.

These two lines of code are *inside* your `foreach` loop:

```
MessageBox.Show("You must select the rows");
return;
```

Which means that *no matter what is checked* the method will *always* `return` after the first iteration of that loop.

I assume that should only happen if no rows are checked?  That should be a separate condition outside of the loop then.  Create a variable to track if any rows were checked.  If any were, update that variable.  Then after the loop examine that variable to conditionally show that message.  Something like this:

```
bool hadCheckedRows = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow r_tabla in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(r_tabla.Cells[0].Value);
    if (isChecked)
    {
        hadCheckedRows = true;
        // the rest of your logic to create triggers
    }
}
if (!hadCheckedRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must select the rows");
    return;
}
```

That way the message is only displayed if the loop has finished examining all of the rows and didn't find any where `isChecked` was `true`.

Comment: I just want to double down on proper styling. Many issues become very obvious if the code is consistently formatted and styled.